# Font Awesome icons alignment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap-sass and font-awesome-sass-rails gems and have successfully eradicated duplicate icons (from glyphicons) by adding to bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss:

```
[class^="icon-"] {
  background-image:none;
}
```

However, now I am having the problem of slightly out of line icons.. The glyphicons were perfect before. Now I am seeing:

[image]

I would like to move the icons down a pixel or 2. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the directions for LESS found on the [Font-Awesome Integration section](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration), one should remove the SASS for the glyph icons altogether, rather than just load the Font-Awesome SASS on top of it.  I strongly discourage any approach that merely tries to save appearances by overriding CSS rules that don't need to be there in the first place.

I don't use Rails, but I assume the rough outline would be:

1. Checkout a copy of the [bootstrap-sass repo](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass).
2. Locate the **_bootstrap.scss** file.
3. Replace the `@import "bootstrap/sprites";` with `@import "your/path/to/font-awesome";`, where `your/path/to/` contains the **font-awesome.scss**.
4. Recompile the **bootstrap.scss** (don't forget to minify!).

Comment: Merv, Hey this is a really good suggestion, and one I've taken on board... I made the change, but unfortunately there is still no adjustment in the icon position. Thanks!

Comment: There should be a general way to manipulate the position like in my original question where I wrote [class^="icon-"] {
  background-image:none;
} for the glyphicons.

Comment: Hey it seems there was something else going on.. Not sure exactly what was up, but I made the transition to the sass version of bootstrap, and there were a couple of leftovers that needed cleaning up.

Comment: @Abram Okay, I'm glad that you found it helpful.  As I said, I was sort of shooting in the dark, since I'm not a Rails developer.  If you had a live test page to link to, I'd have been glad to have a look at it.  Sounds like you have it figured out now.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.  I had to comment out:

```
  @iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

from bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file