# HTML: fontawesome icon appears twice

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'm trying to make a webpage with HTML5 and FontAwesome. My problem is:
If I include a FontAwesome icon it appears twice and both copies are kind of piled upon each other (see there: [image](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3086/jdd3e3ks_jpg.htm))

I changed a bit of the fontawesome.css, but after I recognized the problem I copied the file from download again to reset all my changes: Problem's still there. So the part of my .css  says:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

and I include it to the heading by

```
<h3><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>&nbsp;Angebote</h3>
```

Unfortunately I don't really see the problem.

I tried deleting the ":before" in .css (what does it do anyway?), playing with "display:", adding "vertical-alignment" as the star is a bit up in the sky... Nothing helped.

Anybody ever had something similar? The problem appears on Firefox, Opera and IE.

Best regards,
Anna

Comment: it would be helpful with a jsfiddle or some other preview. the provided css, does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330032/font-awesome-icons-alignment.

Answer (score 7):

you could get similar behavior if you forgot to close the `<i>` tag properly
I had multiple icons when I had

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle">
```

instead of

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the issue myself, and I figured out what I needed to fix. 
In bootstrap.css remove

> ```
> .icon-star-empty {   background-position: -144px 0; }
> ```

basically the css is in 2 places, once in bootstrap.css & once in font-awesome.css, so it displays it twice.

Comment: This will only fix the empty star icon. Not a great solution. As per @Martin Harrigan's comment, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330032/font-awesome-icons-alignment) to correct all of the duplicated icons.

Answer (score 0):

I can further into detail, but basically this problem shouldn't show up in 3.0 (released a couple of weeks ago).

This comes from Bootstrap setting classes on the icon- classes in their sprites.less. The instructions say to comment out sprites.less, but a lot of folks missed that. In the new version, there are overrides that fix this issue.

Also, if you want to make using Font Awesome really easy, you can use the Bootstrap CDN: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
.fa-heart:before{content: '';}
```